# Using a different database user for a single request in DataMapper

Tags: oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I'm working on a Rails 3 application that makes calls to a legacy database that has a very rigid permissions structure. Record visibility is set per database user, so when viewing restricted records, I need to use the user's credentials to make the select request.

I can use DataMapper.setup to change the user I'm connected with, but the problem is that this is not request specific: it sets it for all requests coming in.

How can I set DataMapper to use a specific database user for a single or small set of queries, while not affecting the rest of the application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using multiple data-store connections? e.g.

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "oracle:://user1:password1@host")
DataMapper.setup(:restricted, "oracle://user2:password2@host")
```

You can then use the `default` connection as normal, and use the `restricted` connection by wrapping code in a block:

```
DataMapper.repository(:restricted) {
  Person.first
}
```

More information can be found on http://datamapper.org/docs/misc.